# Put method in web api (EF)

Tags: asp.net, api, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am using a web api put method. I need to update two columns in the database. But I'm having an issue on updating both column.

I've got an error stated below

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.'
>
> emp was null.

This is my current code;

```
public class EmployeeController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, [FromBody] Employee emp)
    {
        try
        {
            using (EmpDBContext dbContext = new EmpDBContext())
            {
                var entity = dbContext.Employees.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Index == id);
                if (entity != null)
                {
                    entity.Name = emp.Name;
                    entity.EmpNum = emp.EmpNum;
                    dbContext.SaveChanges();

                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, entity);
                }
                else
                {
                    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound,
                        "Employee with Id " + id.ToString() + " not found to update");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
        }


    }
}
```

Need some advice regarding this issue.

Comment: What does your PUT request look like?

Comment: @Jasen, , I want to update the name and employee number into the database. The name and employee number will be fetch from another API which has been developed by other user.

Comment: You need to figure out why `emp` (the model sent to the API) is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to use any value in c# which is null then you will get 'Object reference error'. You need to see the API calling method to check why emp is coming null.
Below are the possibility -

- Passing parameter name from calling method should exactly same as the name in parameter of the API, in your case it should be emp.
- Check your Employee Model if it matching with your calling method properties.

You can check this info from Network tab of your browser.